# ObjectName incompatible with String FindBug error

Tags: java, findbugs

For my production code resembling the following:

```
public something xyz(String name) {
  return getSomething(abc.get(name));
}
```

Where the method "get" expects javax.management.ObjectName to be passed to it, I am getting the following high priority warning from the Findbugs tool:

```
Bug: String is incompatible with expected argument type javax.management.ObjectName
Pattern id: GC_UNRELATED_TYPES, type: GC, category: CORRECTNESS
```

However, according to javax API docs, I see that one can have ObjectName as a String, as shown on: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html

Is this a problem with Findbugs or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public something xyz(String name) {
    return getSomething(abc.get(new ObjectName(name)));
}
```

Comment: Yes,  but why is it not caught by the compiler?

Comment: What type is abc? If it's just a list, then java will accept "Object" as a parameter, so anything. Findbugs may have some more advanced checking for what type of data is stored in the list.

Comment: because get is defined as get(Object) back from before there was such a thing as generics.